# How to use bloc initialised in one screen in a different screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have two screens in my flutter application `Screen1` and `Screen2`. `Screen1` is the home screen. I navigate from `Screen1` to `Screen2` via

```
Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder<void>(pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => Screen2());
```

and `Screen2` to `Screen1` via

```
 Navigator.pop(context);
```

`Screen1` is statelesswidget:

```
class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MultiBlocProvider(
         providers: [
            BlocProvider<BlocA>(create: (_) => BlocA()),
            BlocProvider<BlocB>(create: (_) => BlocB()),
          ]
         child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Goto Screen 2'),
              onPressed: Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder<void>(pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => Screen2());
            ),
      )
    }
}
```

I would appreciate anyone can provide an answer that will satisfy the following :

1. Want to access the two bloc initialised in the `Screen1` from `Screen2` using

   BlocProvider.value(value: BlocProvider.of(context), child: ...)

without bringing the initialisation of blocs upto the `MaterialApp` widget. Cannot make the `MultiBlocProvider` the parent of `MaterialApp`. I want the blocs only accessed in `Screen1` and `Screen2`. It should not be accessed by other screens.

2. Also when popped from `Screen2` to `Screen1`, the blocs should not be disposed. Hence, continue to maintain state when popped from `Screen2`
3. Should not pass the bloc via constructor or as arguments in `Navigator`

Currently getting following error:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown building Screen2(dirty):
flutter:         BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a BlocA.
flutter:         No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to
flutter: BlocProvider.of<BlocA>().
flutter:
flutter:         This can happen if the context you used comes from a widget above the BlocProvider.
flutter:
flutter:         The context used was: Screen2(dirty)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use the already created bloc instance on new page, you can use `BlocProvider.value`.

Like passing `BlocX` to next route will be like

```dart
 Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
          value: BlocProvider.of<BlocX>(context),
          child: Screen2(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I might go for repository provider on your case. But to pass multiple instance, you can wrap `BlocProvider` two times on route.

```dart
  Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
      value: BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context),
      child: BlocProvider.value(
        value: BlocProvider.of<BlocB>(context),
        child: Screen2(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Currently, I cannot remember any better option, let me know if you've got any.

Now, your second route `Screen2` can access both `BlocB` and `BlocB` instance.

You can get the instance it like, depend on your code structure.

```dart
BlocConsumer<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is BlocAInitial) {
      return Text(state.name);
    }
    return Text("un impleneted");
  },
  listener: (context, state) {},
),
```

> When you create bloc, and like to pass it with `BlocProvider.value(value: BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context),`, you need to use separate context.

More about [`blocprovider`](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocprovider).

Check the demo, It will clarify, I am using Builder instead of creating new widget for context.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Screen1(),
    );
  }
}

class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<BlocA>(create: (_) => BlocA()),
        BlocProvider<BlocB>(create: (_) => BlocB()),
      ],
      child: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => BlocProvider.value(
                    value: BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context),
                    child: BlocProvider.value(
                      value: BlocProvider.of<BlocB>(context),
                      child: Screen2(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen2({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          BlocConsumer<BlocA, BlocAState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is BlocAInitial) {
                return Text(state.name);
              }
              return Text("un impleneted");
            },
            listener: (context, state) {},
          ),
          BlocConsumer<BlocB, BlocBState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is BlocBInitial) {
                return Text(state.name);
              }
              return Text("un impleneted");
            },
            listener: (context, state) {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Find more about [flutterbloccoreconcepts](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts)

Answer (score 0):

you have to elevate `MultiBlocProvider` in the widget tree so that it wraps both screens, e.g. make it a parent of `MaterialApp`

Comment: one of the requirements I have is that I cannot make the MultiBlocProvider the parent of MaterialApp. I want the blocs only accessed in Screen1 and Screen2. It should not be accessed by other screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass bloc elements as a parameter to Screen2

```
final blocAObject = BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context);
Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder<void>(pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => Screen2(bloca:blocAObject));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with initializing in `MaterialApp` while only having the `bloc`s accessible from the two screens, try the following:

```
final blocA = BlocA(); // shared bloc instance
final blocB = BlocB(); // shared bloc instance

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    routes: {
      'screen1': (_) => MultiBlocProvider(
            providers: [
              BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => blocA,
              ),
              BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => blocB,
              ),
            ],
            child: Screen1(),
          ),
      'screen2': (_) => MultiBlocProvider(
            providers: [
              BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => blocA,
              ),
              BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => blocB,
              ),
            ],
            child: Screen2(),
          ),
    },
  );
}
```